# Getting incorrect tag using UITapGestureRecogniser in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am very new to iPhone, i am working with UITapGestureRecognizer on a KASlideShow custom control with single tap. I have added KASlideShow using XIB to slide three images after few interval. My problem is, i am not getting the correct index after tapping on an image. Can you please help me where is my mistake in my below code :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizerInstruction = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnView:)];
[tapGestureRecognizerInstruction setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
tapGestureRecognizerInstruction.delegate = self;

slideshow.delegate = self;
[slideshow setDelay:1]; // Delay between transitions
[slideshow setTransitionDuration:.5]; // Transition duration
[slideshow setTransitionType:KASlideShowTransitionSlide];
[slideshow setImagesContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[slideshow addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizerInstruction];

arraySlideShowImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],nil]; //array of images


for (int i=0; i<[arraySlideShowImages count]; i++) {

slideshow.tag = i;
[slideshow addImage:[arraySlideShowImages objectAtIndex:i]];

}

[slideshow start];


-(void)handleTapOnView:(id)sender
{
    UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UIGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    KASlideShow * slideshow1 = (KASlideShow *)recognizer.view;

    NSLog(@"slide show tag is = %ld", (long)slideshow1.tag);    
}
```

Every time i am getting "slide show tag is" 2, i want to display particular selected image in full screen. Please suggest me to achieve correct tag.

Thanks!

Comment: Log `[slideShow tag]` after your `for loop`, you may understand what's the issue. You may want to get instead `currentIndex`.

Comment: yes @Larme, bcos of for loop i am getting always last array count i.e 2. but how to get the currect index sir?

Comment: you need to create tap gesture for each slideshow.

Comment: It's a property of KaSlideShow it seems from the GitHub.

Comment: Why are you even using tags when you have a reference to the view itself?

Comment: Can you please help me how can i do with reference to the view itself?

Comment: Thanks to all, now its working. I have set tag to the SlideShow delegate methods.

Comment: @user2786: it is wrong approach to get the sub-view tags. please try the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the correct tag.

The tag should be 2 always because of your `arraySlideShowImages` count is 3 and you have wrote the `slideshow.tag = i;` inside the for loop. The tag will get modified three times as 0,1,2.

If you want it be change to 0, 1 and 2 as per the images, you must set the tag to the image views inside the `addImage` method. Also make sure to use the tag property from 1 instead of zero. So set your tag as i+1.

```
for (int i=0; i<[arraySlideShowImages count]; i++) 
{
   [slideshow addImage:[arraySlideShowImages objectAtIndex:i] Index:i+1];
}

//modify your addImage method
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image Index:(int)itemIndex
{
  //your image view tag as itemIndex
}

-(void)handleTapOnView:(id)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;

    UIImageView* clickedImageView = [recognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]?(UIImageView *)recognizer.view:nil;

    NSLog(@"clickedImageView tag is = %d", clickedImageView.tag);    
}
```

Comment: @RamshadThanks, i want tag should change to 0, 1 and 2 as per the images.

Comment: @user2786: I have modified the answer. Please let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

A. Set tag

```
for(int i=0; i<[arraySlideShowImages count]; i++) 
{
[slideshow addImage:[arraySlideShowImages objectAtIndex:i] Index:i+1];
}

//modify your addImage method
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image Index:(int)itemIndex
 {
 //your image view tag as itemIndex
 }
```

1.Add a Method in KASlideShow.h Class

```
@protocol KASlideShowDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)kaSlideShowSingleTap:(KASlideShow *) slideShow;
```

And add below code in Method  handleSingleTap of KASlideShow.m Class

```
if([self.delegaterespondsToSelector:@selector(kaSlideShowSingleTap:)])
[self.delegate   kaSlideShowSingleTap:self];
```

And call below  Delegate method in your View controller(Where you want to get tag)

```
- (void)kaSlideShowSingleTap:(KASlideShow *) slideShow
{
NSLog(@"kaSlideShowSingleTap, index : %@",@(slideShow.currentIndex));          }
```

Comment: Please use it  to achieve correct tag of slideShow.